# Where do I set the first page when I run the default MasterDetailPage?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;
        //Detail = new Playpage();
        MenuPages.Add((int)MenuItemType.Browse, (NavigationPage)Detail);

    }

    public async Task NavigateFromMenu(int id)
    {
        if (!MenuPages.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            switch (id)
            {
                case (int)MenuItemType.Test:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new Playpage()));
                    break;
                case (int)MenuItemType.Browse:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new ItemsPage()));
                    break;
                case (int)MenuItemType.About:
                    MenuPages.Add(id, new NavigationPage(new AboutPage()));
                    break;

            }
        }

        var newPage = MenuPages[id];

        if (newPage != null && Detail != newPage)
        {
            Detail = newPage;

            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
                await Task.Delay(100);

            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
```

This code is approximately the same as the defalut MasterDetailpage that appears when the first page is created. However, I can't found the first page part. If I want to change the page that starts the first time, Is this code being modified or is there any other code?

Comment: Are you talking about the first page that is shown when you start your app?  That is set in App.xaml.cs using the `MainPage` property.  It has nothing to do with MasterDetail

Comment: nope, On MasterDetailPage detail

Comment: @Carrot135 If you want to set masterdetailpage's default detailed page when you open MasterDetailPage, just set `Detail = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage())`, Microsoft article about MasterDetailPage:[Xamarin.Forms Master-Detail Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it like 
`Detail = new HomePage();` in your MasterDetailPage constructor